Midi system connections
What could the possible MIDI connections be for linking the following hardware in order to get them all working together in unison?

controller(Midiplus EK490+)
drum machine(Roland TR-505)
sampler(Roland S-10)
sequencer/synthesizer(Kurzweil K2000Sv.3)

The first two units just have midi in/out, while the others have midi in/out/thru.
I've been recently getting back into making music with hardware MIDI gear in semi-DAWless(ly) fashion, using the computer mainly for recording only.
My knowledge on midi daisy-chaining stuff is a little rusty, related to midi cable patching schematics.

'Using the computer for recording only' doesn't have to mean NOT using it for MIDI routing.   And do you really want the drum machine to be played 'in unison' with other instruments from a keyboard controller?   Hook up a multi-port MIDI interface to your computer.  If you only want to use the DAW program for MIDI routing and recording, that's fine.
If you want to do a simple MIDI daisy-chain, obviously the controller needs to come first.  Then the two units with both MIDI In and Out, in any order. Lastly the Roland TR-505 as it doesn't have MIDI Through.  The computer won't receive MIDI at all in this setup.
Then you'll have to either combine the audio outputs of each device in an external mixer and feed the mix into the computer's one audio input, or add a multi-channel audio interface to the computer.

Yep thanx I appreciate that info & will take it under advisement but I'd just like to midi daisy-chain all four of those instruments together so as to utilize each's midi voices (notes) forming stuff in that way & recording the results with the computer. What''s the best order, schematically Midi wise as far as what should be hooked up to what in the configuration using the IN/OUT/THRU of: controller=>drum machine=>sampler=sequencer/synth

OK.  I've expanded my answer.
